# Branch of Mathematics: 'shapes caused by energy and forces'?

Tags: geometry

I've been researching the many branches of mathematics, and learning the complete basics about Einstein field equations, and graph theory, and topology.

Considering *a graph with three vertices and three edges*, I wondered, is there a branch of mathematics related to common shapes (triangles, squares, circles) formed as a result of applied energy or force?

For example, using my fingers, I can, with a little bit of effort, make a triangle shape using an elastic band. Is there a branch of maths dealing with applying and/or measuring the energy applied to the formation of such shapes?

It seems to me, in order for me to form a near perfect triangle, the energy applied to the elastic must be the same in each of the 3 points of energy or force applied to the elastic band, in this example.

Then - if each point of a triangle represent some level of resistance, then if each of the points would each contain the *energy* required to form and maintain the shape.

Comment: Well "applied energy" and "force" aren't really terms you'll find in pure mathematics that often, if at all, but what you're looking for is Differential Geometry or Topology. Those areas of mathematics are used to describe the kinds of things you're talking about. General relativity uses a lot of Differential Geometry for instance.

Comment: I see, yes - indeed, learning about applied, pure, discrete mathematics too. OK. Seems, if each edge is 'forced' to form the triangle shape, then each edge would - in a sense - contain and represent the level of energy necessary to form and maintain the shape. For example: Edge 1 = 5, Edge 2 = 5, Edge 3 = 5 (Triangle). Type of thing.

Comment: I'm no physicist/engineer, but I believe the energy required to form this rubber band triangle is only dependent on its length at the end. You can calculate this energy as the integral of force over distance stretched. All that is left is an expression for the tension in the band relative to distance stretched, and you can calculate it.

Comment: I see. Distance/length of vertices determining how much 'force' is required to form a standard triangle. Then, each of the vertices and edges would, as it were, 'contain', and therefore be described numerically. What is a basic way to express this?
'Material'(String/Edges)' + Distance'(X) + 'Force'(Y) = 'Shape'(Z)?

Comment: One subject in this spirit is that of "minimal surfaces" in differential geometry. In particular, Plateau's problem in mathematics is named after Joseph Plateau who experimented with realizing such surfaces by experiments on soap films.

Comment: This seem related - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/wint.html - for search term: "integral of force over distance". Plenty of results to check.

Comment: Look up "physically based shape modeling".

Comment: @lhf - I see - from a perspective of 3D animation, the possibility of shapes morphing from one to another. And considering, after quick look up, significance of 'General Topology or Point Set Topology'. I think this is a more programmatic way to see the idea, for me. But, I wondered about the 'intrinsic' nature of the shape, mathematically - and if whether shapes follow the same 'rule' applicable to each shape.

Comment: @Semiclassical - great to see how seemingly unrelated subjects are actually related. Joseph Plateau is a modern-day pre-Socratic (Experimental, Empirical). And then related to Calculus. Then, 'Geometric measure theory'.